# Drupal 7 images not displaying

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

For some reason, images are not showing up when not logged in as an administrator.

The issue seems to be connected to my use of views.

The images are part of a content type I created. The field type is image and I can pull the images from the node when accessing the node in a custom template and not using views.

But when using views, the images only show up when I'm logged in as an administrator.

I don't have any field/content permission modules installed, this is pretty bare bones with a Zen theme sub-themed. And I'm not doing anything funky with the view, just create it and add the fields I want to display. It works fine as administrator.

I can't seem to figure this one out. It seems like this is a permissions issue, but I don't see anything in the permissions configuration that would affect this behavior.

Any tips?

Comment: Is the View published? (As in, you clicked "Save"). Can you post a screenshot of your View configuration page?

Comment: Yeah, it's saved. Non-logged in users can see the view, all of the data shows up except the photos. But I can create a custom page, and access the photos for non-logged in users and they show up fine. So it doesn't appear to be a permissions issue, unless the View has some permissions stuff going on.

I also created another super-simple view and the same thing happens with images not showing up if you're not logged in as admin.

It's weird.

![Screenshot of View](http://take88.com/images/view-shot.png).

Comment: That's odd. Do you have any media/file-altering modules installed? Out-of-the-box, everything should be public, so this is really weird.

Comment: This is a straight-out-of-box drupal install. I'm using all of the standard media stuff. What's weird is that I can access the images for non-logged in users when not using a view.

I guess, I'll just not use Views, but that kind of sucks.

Comment: Well if you don't mind, maybe you can create a user for me and I can have a look around. If you can access the images fine without Views, it's definitely a Views issue. Possibly even a field.

Comment: I would, but it's not a publicly accessible site at this point. I think I'll do another fresh drupal install and just try and create the content-type and view and see if it works in there, if so, then there's something borked in my Drupal install. I'll post my results here.

Comment: Well, it works when I create a fresh drupal install, a content type and a view to show the content with the photos.

Something is messed up with my drupal install. This is my biggest complaint about Drupal, you can end up with a broken system sometimes and there's seemingly no way to fix it.

Thanks again for your help, this one was/is a head-scratcher.

Comment: Yeah, no problem. Sorry I wasn't of much help. You're right, Drupal has a knack for breaking out of nowhere. I had major headaches setting up a small Drupal Commerce store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate that this is an old post but after days of trying to resolve the problem I have seen many of these posts and want to update with my solution.

My web host is classed as a shared web host which means for me that I don't have as much access to the server side as with other hosts. The control area for the admin on my host is custom and lots of stuff that I have with another host and previous hosts id missing.

I resolved the images not showing by adjusting the .htaccess file. There are 2 that I have found so far in Drupal 7.24 (one in the site root and one in sites/default/files/) and I had to adjust both of them by commenting out the options section and the symlinks section. There is info on this by googling "one.com Drupal Installation".

Once both htaccess files had been edited and the permissions had been changed on the "files" folder in "sites/default/" to "755" the extra folders where created when I uploaded my images and the images started to show fine. If like me you are unable to change permissions within your website hosts control panel you will need to do it with either an ftp client or via ssh.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem sometimes usually I cange folder and image files permissions to 0777 if all is ok to 0755.

Comment: That's not it, because I can access the images for any user (anonymous) when not using a view, it's something related to Views, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

admin->people->permissions->check 'view files' for anonymous user, save permissions. 
Those images you uploaded with some multi-uploading modules are regarded as files, anonymous user need permission to view   them.